# How to untar a file in nohup mode

Tags: linux, tar, nohup

I would like to untar a file in `nohup`-mode as the tarball is more than 200 GB in size. The command I am using is

```
nohup tar -xf aem-backup.tar
```

However, this throws the error

```
-bash: $'nohup\302\240tar': command not found
```

What am I doing wrong here, and is there a better option?

Comment: What does `which nohup` return? If this returns nothing, then it is most likely that you did not install `nohup` or your `$PATH` does not contain the directory where the `nohup` binary is located.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the command , what you should look at is "command not found" error . Check if you have coreutils rpm . If so try and search in /bin or /usr/bin folder for nohup using find command and then try use full path or create an alias .

Comment: I would also suggest you to probably do this without nohup and see if you still get the error  \302\204 error ? See if you have copied some illegal characters in command ?

Comment: \302 \240: 302 240 (octal) → 0xC2 0xA0 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128)).

Comment: NO-BREAK SPACE is known to be introduced by copying code through [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat). It can be searched (and replaced) for by using the regular expression `\x{00A0}` in any modern text editor or IDE. Note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u00A0` (instead of `\x{00A0}`)

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 1):

The error says 'nohup\302\240tar' command not found , with stray characters 302 and 240 . It seems there are some invisible characters instead of space between nohup and tar . Try to type the command rather than copying it from somewhere and see if that works for you.

```
 'nohup\302\240tar': command not found
```